# How does an equilibrium index of an array work?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I tried a demo test on Codility for finding the equilibrium index(es) of an array.  I'm not sure if the test was to find the equilibrium indexes of an array or what.  I googled around and found the following example:

> The equilibrium index of a sequence is an index such that the sum of elements at lower indexes is equal to the sum of elements at higher indexes. For example, in a sequence A:
>
> `A[0]=-7  A[1]=1  A[2]=5  A[3]=2  A[4]=-4  A[5]=3  A[6]=0`
>
> 3 is an equilibrium index, because:
>
> `A[0] + A[1] + A[2] = A[4] + A[5] +A[6]`
>
> 6 is also an equilibrium index, because:
>
> `A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] = 0`

Based on this information I see the test array contains 7 elements.  It looks like the middle element `A[3]=2` is being ignored.  Is it because it is between the first 3 elements and the last 3 elements?  How is the equilibrium index of 6 arrived at in this example?

Here is the method that was used to compute this:

```
int equi(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n==0) return -1; 
    long long sum = 0;
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) sum+=(long long) arr[i]; 

    long long sum_left = 0;    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        long long sum_right = sum - sum_left - (long long) arr[i];
        if (sum_left == sum_right) return i;
        sum_left += (long long) arr[i];
    } 
    return -1; 
}
```

When I took the Codility demo test I used the method (below) with the `for` loops initially beginning at 0.  I received a "wrong answer" message for the test case of `1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0` and that Codility was looking for a result of 11.

I modified the two `for` loops in my method and started the first loop at `i = 1` and the second loop at `i = 2` until it yielded a result of 11, which Codility was satisfied with.  I basically just tweaked the method until Codility was happy (I was shooting for 11 because Codility specified that was the answer they were looking for), but I don't really know why Codility was happy or what was the significance of my tweaks -- just hit and miss:

```
        ...
        int[] B = new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0 };

        Console.WriteLine(solution3(B));
    }

    public int solution3(int[] A)
    {
        long rsum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < A.Count(); i++)
            rsum += A[i];

        long lsum = A[0];
        int min = (int)Math.Abs(lsum - rsum);
        
        for (int i = 2; i < A.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            lsum += A[i];
            rsum -= A[i];
            int diff = (int)Math.Abs(lsum - rsum);
            if (diff >= min)
                min = diff;
        }

        return min;
    }
```

Why did this tweak (of hit and miss) satisfy the Codility test?  What is an equilibrium index actually?  How is it arrived at?  Note: if there are steps between step A and step E (which I would have to intuit the in between steps) what are steps B, C, and D?

Answer (score 4):

**What is an equilibrium index and how is it determined?**

Think of your array like a board with weights of different sizes on it (negative weights can be thought of as helium balloons attached to the board).  Each weight is numbered from left to right.  Your task is to place a fulcrum under the board at any of the numbered positions to make the board balance.  (We will treat the board itself as weightless, and assume distance of the weights from the center doesn't matter.)  Whichever positions make the board balance are the equilibrium indexes.  The weight at the fulcrum doesn't "count" because it's not on either side; it is in the middle.

Here is a picture of the first example:

[image: Equilibrium index = 3]

Here, 3 is an equilibrium index, because the sum of the weights to the left of the fulcrum equal the sum of the weights to the right of the fulcrum (-7 + 5 + 1 = -1 = -4 + 3 + 0).

Here is the second example:

[image: Equilibrium index = 6]

We see that 6 is also an equilibrium index for the same reason.  All the elements to the left of the fulcrum add up to zero.  As there are no elements to the right of the fulcrum, that sum is also zero.

The basic algorithm to find the equilibrium indexes is this:

1. Loop over the array and add up all the elements.  Call this sum `total`.
2. Initialize a variable `left_sum` to zero.
3. Initialize a variable `right_sum` to `total`.
4. Now loop over the array a second time.  For each array item:

   1. Subtract the value of the current item from `right_sum`.
   2. Compare the `left_sum` to the `right_sum`.  If they are equal, then the index of the current item is an equilibrium index.
   3. Add the value of the current item to `left_sum`.

And that's all there is to it.  Does it make sense now?

---

**What's going on with my algorithm?**

As for why the "Codility demo test" was expecting a result of 11 for an array containing the elements `{ 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0 }`, I cannot say.  You never said in your question what the demo problem actually was.  If the problem was to find the first equilibrium index in that array, then the answer is that there is none for that array.  Stepping through the above algorithm, here are the left and right sums for each array index:

```
Index  Left  Right
-----  ----  -----
    0     0     12
    1     1      7
    2     6      5
    3     8      4
    4     9      0
    5    13      0
```

As you can see, there is no index at which the left sum equals the right sum.  An expected result of `11` does not even make sense anyway because there are only six elements.  So if there were an equilibrium index for this array, it would have to between 0 and 5 inclusive.  So I'm guessing the problem posed must have been something else.  You would have to include the problem statement in your question before I could even begin to guess why your algorithm is or isn't correct.

Comment: "Loop over the array and add up all the elements. Call this sum total." -> such operations might sound trivial however one must take into account scenarios concerning underflows / overflows which can wreak havoc. Even if the algorithm is sound in broad-strokes I suspect it must be adjusted to somehow compensate for the aforementioned shortcoming in an elegant manner which is non-trivial. Just my 2c.

Comment: @XDS Agreed, if there are no limits placed on the inputs. I did a quick search to try to find the Codility problem in question and found [this one](https://app.codility.com/tasks/equi/) which seems to match the OP's description. This problem places limits on the size of each element as being in the range [−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647] and the number of elements in the array as being in the range [0..100,000]. So if you used longs to keep the sums, you would not run into any overflow/underflow issues with this algorithm.

Comment: "if there are no limits placed on the inputs" <- we could quote Murphy's Law here but I think we can do even better: "don't worry Jeff, there certainly are some limits placed on these inputs that our mechanism is being supplied with" <- famous last words

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on what I understand about an equilibrium index of an array I came up with the following algorithm which I tested on another array which has equilibrium indexes as index 3 and index 6, but I also tested this algorithm on the original array which returned a -1 (nothing to do with an 11).  Here is the sample:

```
        private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int[] arr = new int[7] { -7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0 }; //--new array
        int[] arr = new int[6] { 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0 };  //--original array
        List<int> lst = new List<int>();
        int p = arr.Length;
        int i = 0;
        int q = 0;
        int t = 0;
        do
        {
            t = equilibrium(arr, arr.Length, q);
            if (lst.IndexOf(t) == -1)
                lst.Add(t);
            q = t;
            i++;
        } while (i < p);

        foreach (var m in lst)
            Console.WriteLine(m);            
    }

    private int equilibrium( int[] arr, int n, int q1)
    {
       int i, j;
       int leftsum, rightsum;

       for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       {
          leftsum = 0;
          rightsum = 0;

          for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
             leftsum += arr[j];

          for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
             rightsum += arr[j];

          if (leftsum == rightsum && q1 != i)
             return i;
       }

       return -1;
    }
```

This algorithm makes sense to me, but when I tried it on Codility with an array of int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 2, 1, 0, 1 };  I got a "wrong Answer -- expected 3"  In my test app my algorithm returned a 1 which is what it returned on Codility.  Where did they come up with 3 for this array?  Thus, I do not understand the equilibrium index of an array.  Any suggestions appreciated.